# How to give dynamic json filename as url in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here I am using ajax call to get the json object from controller.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          cache: false, 
          type: "GET",
          url: "userid_12345.json",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){    
           somemethod();
          },
          error:function(){
            alert("Sorry!");
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Here, this userid_12345.json file will be in same path. 
There will be multiple json files will be there based on the userid like `userid_12345.json`, `userid_22345.json`, `userid_55345.json`.

So, I need to give dynamic URL's to get the .json file from the path.
something like this.. `userid_?.json`. ? will replace the userid

How to achieve this?

Comment: create file variable outside the $.ajax function & append the user id to file variable.. that's it.. use that variable into the ajax function

Comment: Any working example?

Comment: Is the user_id related to logged in user? I mean u just want access json file for logged in user??

Comment: Yes after the user login, controller will send the particular .json file which was appended with userid. So I need to get the particular .json file

Comment: what are you using in backend??

Comment: when the user logins, based on the userid, it will fetch the query string from db and convert it to json object. Then it will put it in a separate file with .json format in the same path. I  need to fetch the .json file and process in html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63571/discussion-between-bhushya-and-dinesh-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<script>

      var myDynUrl = "http://wherever/userid_" + dynamicValue + ".json"

      $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
          cache: false, 
          type: "GET",
          url: myDynUrl,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){    
           somemethod();
          },
          error:function(){
            alert("Sorry!");
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. how can I get the dynamic value?

Answer (score 0):

just add a variable (outside the `$.ajax` request) that cantains the user id
`var myUserId = "12345";` than in the url `url: "userid_" + myUserId + ".json",`